# How do I tidy this dadmom dataset?

Tags: r, datatable, format, tidy

can anyone help me tidy this dataset in R?

This is the original form:

```
## # A tibble: 3 x 5
    ##   famid named  incd namem  incm
    ##   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
    ## 1     1 Bill  30000 Bess  15000
    ## 2     2 Art   22000 Amy   18000
    ## 3     3 Paul  25000 Pat   50000
```

I'm trying to convert it to this form:

```
## # A tibble: 6 x 4
    ##   famid parent name    inc
    ##   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
    ## 1     1 d      Bill  30000
    ## 2     1 m      Bess  15000
    ## 3     2 d      Art   22000
    ## 4     2 m      Amy   18000
    ## 5     3 d      Paul  25000
    ## 6     3 m      Pat   50000
```

Thanks!

I've been trying to use pivot_longer but keep receiving errors from R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata <- tribble(
~famid, ~named, ~ incd, ~namem,  ~incm,
 1, "Bill",  30000, "Bess",  15000,
 2, "Art",   22000, "Amy",   18000,
 3, "Paul",  25000, "Pat",   50000)

mydata |> 
  rename(name_d = named, inc_d = incd, name_m = namem, inc_m = incm) |> 
  pivot_longer(!famid, names_to = c(".value", "parent"), names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  famid parent name    inc
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1     1 d      Bill  30000
2     1 m      Bess  15000
3     2 d      Art   22000
4     2 m      Amy   18000
5     3 d      Paul  25000
6     3 m      Pat   50000
```

Answer (score 1):

As a one liner with `pivot_longer` and `names_pattern`...

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

mydata <- tribble(
  ~famid, ~named, ~ incd, ~namem,  ~incm,
  1, "Bill",  30000, "Bess",  15000,
  2, "Art",   22000, "Amy",   18000,
  3, "Paul",  25000, "Pat",   50000)

mydata |> 
  pivot_longer(!famid, names_to = c(".value", "parent"), names_pattern = "(.*)([dm]$)")
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   famid parent name    inc
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 d      Bill  30000
#> 2     1 m      Bess  15000
#> 3     2 d      Art   22000
#> 4     2 m      Amy   18000
#> 5     3 d      Paul  25000
#> 6     3 m      Pat   50000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>